# Input in PrimeFaces datatable header does not update backing bean - solution?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

If I place an input component outside of the data table, then the backing bean is updated with the input and the search works just fine, displaying the results correctly in the data table.

```
<h:form>
<!-- ------- Calendar input component outside dataTable ------- -->
    <p:calendar id="selectHireDate" value="#{backingBean.hireDateToSearch}" />

    <p:dataTable id="employeeDataTable"
        value="#{backingBean.employeeDataModel}" var="employee">
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column>                           
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Lorem Ipsum
                        </f:facet>                          
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{employee.hireDate}" />
        </p:column>     
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit"
    actionListener="#{backingBean.searchEmployees}"
    update="employeeDataTable" />
</h:form>
```

However, if I place that input component in the header of the data table, suddenly the backing bean is no longer updated.  (I placed a breakpoint on backingBean.setHireDateToSearch which gets tripped by the code above but not the code below.)

```
<h:form>            
    <p:dataTable id="employeeDataTable"
        value="#{backingBean.employeeDataModel}" var="employee">
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column>                           
                        <f:facet name="header">
<!-- ------- Calendar input component inside dataTable ------- -->
                            <p:calendar id="selectHireDate" value="#{backingBean.hireDateToSearch}" />
                        </f:facet>                          
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{employee.hireDate}" />
        </p:column>     
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit"
    actionListener="#{backingBean.searchEmployees}"
    update="employeeDataTable" />
</h:form>
```

Why is this?  Is there a way to make the latter set-up work?

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your problem and it get solved when I get rid of the `<p:columnGroup>` around the `<f:facet name="header">` which does by itself not make much sense in this construct anyway.

```
<p:dataTable id="employeeDataTable" value="#{backingBean.employeeDataModel}" var="employee">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:calendar id="selectHireDate" value="#{backingBean.hireDateToSearch}" />
    </f:facet>                          
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{employee.hireDate}" />
    </p:column>     
</p:dataTable>
```

*(this only shows a second tiny line of empty `<p:column>` headers, you could just hide it by a little CSS)*

Not sure if this is caused by design or by a bug somewhere in a `decode()` method associated with `<p:dataTable>`. I'd [report](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) it to the PrimeFaces guys to be sure.

Comment: I'd like to preserve the row in the header, though, since my table will have two header rows.  I don't see a way to eliminate the columnGroup and preserve the rows.  Do you see a solution?

Comment: @Kiwi Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: I have a similar issue with p:selectBooleanCheckbox... described here: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=37163 Are these problems related? Bug? PS: We're using PF 3.5.25. @Balusc: do you remember which bug you reported?